# Wordlist/dictionary generation for penetration testing

Tags: password, performance, dictionary

How can I generate a dictionary of words containing 8-16 of alphabet characters (`[a-zA-Z]`) with low memory?

Comment: I don't see at all what's unclear about this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked how to create one, but just in case you want one: https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/29308-13gb-44gb-compressed-wpa-wpa2-word-list-982963904-words/

As for creating one, consider checking out a program called [`crunch`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) (wordlist generator).